# Laravel Backpack Admin CRUD Views returning 404

Tags: laravel-backpack

I had this working on a local dev environment, but now that I'm pushing it live I'm running into an error:

When I try to access my CRUD pages (/admin/images or similar), I get taken to my websites 404 page.

I uploaded the /routes/admin.php file, all my resource files, controllers, models, vendor files, public/vendor files, and probably some others I'm forgetting to mention.

**Not sure if theres something in the config files for backpack I need to edit or what.** Looking for some direction.

Note: I am able to access the default routes from Backpack (dashboard, login, logout)

**RouteServiceProvider.php**

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}

protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
         ->middleware('api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}

protected function mapAdminRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware(['web', 'admin'])
         ->prefix('admin') // or use the prefix from CRUD config
         ->namespace($this->namespace.'\Admin')
         ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
}
```

Found this error in the error logs:

> exception 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException'
>   with message 'Call to undefined relationship [wheels] on model
>   [App\Models\WheelFinishes].' in
>   laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/RelationNotFoundException.php:20

But I have the relationship defined in my **WheelFinishes model**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Backpack\CRUD\CrudTrait;

class WheelFinishes extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;

    public function wheels()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Wheels', 'wheel_id');
    }

    ...
}
```

**Wheels Model**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Backpack\CRUD\CrudTrait;
use App\User;

class Wheels extends Model
{
use CrudTrait;

protected $table = "wheels";
protected $primaryKey = 'id';

...

public function tips()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\WheelTips', 'wheel_id');
}

public function finishes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\WheelFinishes', 'wheel_id')->where('status', '=', '1')->orderBy('order');
}

public function factoryFinishes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\WheelFinishes', 'wheel_id')->where('status', '=', '1')->where('factory_finish', '=', '1')->orderBy('order');
}

public function wheelImages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\WheelImages', 'wheel_id');
}

public function wheelImage()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\WheelFinishes', 'wheel_id')->where('status', '=', '1')->orderBy('order');
}

public function profile()
{
    return $this->BelongsTo('App\Models\Profile');
}

public function series()
{
    return $this->BelongsTo('App\Models\Series');
}

public function vehicles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Vehicles', 'wheel_id')->where('status', '=', '1')->orderBy('order')->take(3);
}

public function vehicle()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Vehicles', 'wheel_id')->where('status', '=', '1')->orderBy('order');
}
```

}

**routes.php**

```
<?php

// Backpack\CRUD: Define the resources for the entities you want to CRUD.
CRUD::resource('video', 'VideoCrudController');
CRUD::resource('wheels', 'WheelCrudController');
Route::get('finishes/ajax-finishes-options', 'FinishCrudController@wheelsOptions');
CRUD::resource('finishes', 'FinishCrudController');
Route::get('albums/ajax-albums-options', 'AlbumCrudController@albumsOptions');
CRUD::resource('albums', 'AlbumCrudController');
CRUD::resource('heros', 'HeroCrudController');
```

Comment: ```routes/admin.php``` does not sound like a default Laravel/Backpack route file. Are you loading it anywhere?

Comment: can you post some code for reference please?

Comment: @tabacitu I have it loaded in my RouteServiceProvider as mentioned in the docs

Comment: @Indra sorry, I wasn't sure what code to show at first, but I found some I think is helpful

Comment: Do you have the model wheels? Is the namespace correct in the model? Can you show the route for admin/images from the admin.php routes?

Comment: @Indra added as requested

Comment: BelongsTo should be belongsTo, but i don't think that's the issue. Still looking at the code. Will let you know. Edit: I would debug the code using dd until I find the source. Do non Crud controllers work?

Comment: exception 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException' with message 'Call to undefined relationship [wheels] on model [App\Models\WheelFinishes] Did you import the namespaces in the file where you make this call?

Comment: I tried using `dd()` on my controller and model, but it seems the error is starting before those care called because it never showed me anything else. Any other ideas where I should try it?

What namespaces do I need to import? I have `CrudTrait` and `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`...my function in the model also references `App\Models\WheelFinishes`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a separate route file you probably need to register it in RouteServiceProvider:

```
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/web.php');
        require base_path('routes/admin.php');
    });
```

Comment: Its written differently, but I have it registered as documented in the Backpack docs (added to original question)